# Is it true that $\lim (f+g)(x) = \lim f(x) + \lim g(x)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to know when exactly could we write :

$$ \lim (f+g)(x)= \lim f(x) + \lim g(x).$$

Does this depend on where the limit is calculated and what it is?
I need this for limits calculating with squeeze theorem and with equalities.

Comment: since $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$, it suffices to know that both $\text{lim}f(x)$ and $\text{lim}g(x)$ exist as finite real numbers.

Comment: This webpage http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitProofs.aspx answers your question exactly. In the future, please do a bit more research before asking questions.

Comment: You need one of the limits on the right to exist finitely. The more interesting case is regarding product rule where you need one of the limits to be non-zero and finite for the rule to work.

Answer (score 7):

Let's get a small notational thing aside. What exactly does $(f+g)(x)$ mean? It means $f(x) + g(x)$. So you are really asking whether
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} [f(x) + g(x)] = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) + \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x). \tag{1}$$
And the answer is "sometimes." If $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ both exist and are finite, then the proposed identity is true.

But for instance you might have $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = -x$. Then $f(x) + g(x) = 0$, then the left hand side of $(1)$ is zero, but neither limit on the right hand side exists.